# Vhosts only working in one case not the other

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Pinging both www.example.com and example.com show that my ip address is correct

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV live
</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing www.example.com works fine, however when I access example.com I see the default it works message (which is storred in /var/www/index.html)

Pinging both www.example.com and example.com show that my ip address is correct,
what other steps can I do to figure out the root of the problem?

Comment: You have example.com already in the ServerName. You don't need it in the ServerAlias too.

Comment: Cool, I just added that extra alias under frustration, didn't work without it

Answer (score 2):

Try separating your ServerName's.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV live
</VirtualHost>
```

(Although as the first comment says, you shouldn't need to have a serveralias for example.com as it's your server-name)

Are there any other VHosts? What's the default server-name in httpd.conf (If it was example.com, that would override the vhost, I think)

Comment: +1, I second that there's probably other vhosts loading first and taking the name.